# При вводе текста в EditText съезжает ActionBar (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, actionbar

Делаю тестовый редактор. У меня есть EditText на весь экран. Если нажать на текст (так, чтобы открылась клавиатура), который находится достаточно низко, экшнбар съезжает наверх. Как отключить это? Заранее спасибо за ответы.
[image: Клавиатура не открыта]

[image: Клавиатура открыта и экшн бар съехал]

Верстка активити:

```
    editor = new EditText(this);
    editor.setTextSize(pref.getInt(PREF_TEXT_SIZE, SIZE_MEDIUM));
    editor.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    editor.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    editor.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    editor.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    setContentView(editor);
```

Активити в манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Покажите вёрстку и объявление активити в манифесте, а также динамический каст toolbar, все сразу станет ясно.

Comment: Вёрстку и манифест добавил, а динамический каст тулбара это что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать для Layout'а, где у вас находится редактор текста свойство:

android:isScrollContainer="false"

А в манифесте вашей активити:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!